# Blank project pages in uWamp

Tags: localhost, uwamp

I have seen a lot of messages talking about wamp and how to actually just modify one line or two to

> Revert WAMPServer 2.5 "Your Projects" links to pre 2.5 mechanism

and how to index.php in www folder and set

change line 30:

```
$suppress_localhost = true
```

So About the port. Is already fixed on my end I had to go to apacheconfig button in uwamp and just change the port to 8012 for main-serveur virtual server.

I either would like to know how I can manage to actually do the same as in WAMP and modify that supress localhost option. Or learn to do a virtualhost in Uwamp. Hope anybody could help me.

phpmyadmin works!

index.php  works!

subdirectory inside www does not work

Answer (score 0):

What is you code in subdirectory?

A simple code like this

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```

in a index.php file inside subdirectory work?